# Clicking or Knocking with Seagate HD

Tags: hard-drive

My laptop's main HD makes a clicking or knocking sound when Windows or the Bios tries to access it. I put it into a SATA dock and it sounds perfectly fine when spinning up, but after Windows tries to access it, it becomes a repetitive clicking or knocking sound.

Does anyone know any tips that might help me access my data? It locks up parts Windows XP and Ghost with WinPE, so I am unable to access my data.

I have most of it backed up, but I would still like to Ghost it before I send it off for repairs. I know my laptop is still under warranty.

Answer (score 3):

That clicking is the HD recalibrating the heads. Which means the disk is failing. It might take a very long time before it stops working all together, so no need to panic. But you should backup all your data soon, and send it in for replacement.

There's a wiki article on the sound you described, the [Click of Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death).

Comment: How might you suggest I pull of the data? It locks up the OS that tries to access it.