# Recovering/Repairing an external HD

Tags: external-hard-drive, repair

My external HD gave out on me yesterday. I thought: let it rest for a while, but nothing gives. Before this, it was falling off and going back on every few minutes. I got tired of this and turned it off. Now it won't go back on.

It's one of those HD's where's there's a switch at the back that you have to flip.
Everything is connected properly. USB connection is good, AC connection is also good.

When I flip the switch and listen, the HD doesn't start spinning like usual. It's very silent, but when I lay my ear on it, I can hear something ticking inside, like 2 small pieces of the metal tapping against each other. Far as I can tell, the HD is *trying* to start properly, but failing.

It also doesn't show up on the explorer overview anymore.

I only got my laptop at to use, so I'm not sure how to do this. I could screw the HD open, get the disk out and connect it to Laptop, but if the problem is that the disk won't start spinning, that won't do me any good.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a repeat of many such questions.  The tapping sound you are hearing is a retry - the hard drive can't read the track markers correctly and keeps retrying.  The following two links have some suggestions you can try.

[Clicking or Knocking with Seagate HD](https://superuser.com/questions/140575/clicking-or-knocking-with-seagate-hd)

[Hard drive won't initialize, spins up, makes 2 clicks, and spins up again](https://superuser.com/questions/23476/hard-drive-wont-initialize-spins-up-makes-2-clicks-and-spins-up-again)